# XAML Designer Crashes in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: xaml, crash, visual-studio-2012

When I load up a XAML file in the designer I get the below exception and then I have to kill VS 2012 from the process manager. Any ideas on work arounds?

```
Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TResult,TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Func`2 func, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalHostTextBufferSynchronizer.get_IsReadOnly()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.DesignerTextBufferSynchronizer.get_IsReadOnly()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.DesignerTextBuffer.get_IsReadOnly()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Documents.TextBuffer.get_IsReadOnly()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Documents.SceneDocument.get_IsReadOnly()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Documents.SceneDocument.get_IsUndoTargetReadOnly()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Selection.SelectionSet`2.SetSelectionWithUndo(String description, ListOfT newSelection, T newPrimarySelection)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Selection.SceneNodeSelectionSet.SetSelectionWithUndo(String description, SceneNodeOrderedCollection newSelection, SceneNode newPrimarySelection)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Selection.SelectionSet`2.ExtendSelection(T selectionToExtend)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.SceneViewModel.SelectNodes(ICollection`1 nodes)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.View.SceneView.SelectionSynchronizer.OnCaretPositionChangedTimeoutTimerTick(TextEditorContext textEditor)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.View.SceneView.SelectionSynchronizer.SynchronizeSceneToMarkup(TextEditorContext textEditor)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.View.SceneView.TextEditor_CaretPositionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.TextEditorContext.CaretPositionChangedPipe(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalEvent`2.<>c__DisplayClass12.<Invoke>b__10()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.Invoke(Boolean waitingInExternalCall)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.InvokeCall(Call call)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessQueue(CallQueue queue)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessInboundQueue(Int32 identity)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, Boolean elevatedQuery, Boolean& handled)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.OnWindowMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.MessageOnlyHwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationProcess.RunApplication()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationProcess.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Main>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn[TResult](IRemoteObject targetObject, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteHostTextBufferSynchronizer.get_IsReadOnly()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteHostTextBufferSynchronizer.get_IsReadOnly()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalHostTextBufferSynchronizer.<get_IsReadOnly>b__8(IRemoteHostTextBufferSynchronizer hs)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass4`2.<MarshalOut>b__3()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteHostTextBufferSynchronizer.<get_IsReadOnly>b__7()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass16`1.<MarshalIn>b__15()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is a bit old but I had a similar problem in VS2013, found a clue from an MSDN article and checked the event viewer for exceptions, look for XDesProc.exe.

The problem was an out of date driver for my graphics card.

Once that was updated all started working again

It might help someone